# Can I used android's OTA system to update a custom app?

Tags: android, updates, ota

I have been looking at android OTA capabilities recently:

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/

And after a lot of googling and reading I am still quite confused,
Can I use this OTA thing android has for its system file and read only apps to update my own custom application?

EDIT:

I ask this because I am still searching for a way to update a application on the android device without requiring human interaction to confirm, etc. This is because I want to use the phone with an embedded system that is in a box which is hard to get into.

Comment: Are you building your own custom ROM? If so, then yes, the OTA can update your custom app (assuming that your custom app is part of the custom ROM). Or, if it is your own custom ROM, you should be able to give something the ability to silently update apps, the way the Play Store does. If, OTOH, you are not implementing a custom ROM, then the OTA system has nothing to do with your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't OTA upgrades are meant to be used by carrier providers, they will sent the OTA upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

OTA updates are intended to update the whole read-only partitions. Usually, it's Android- and SoC- specific partitions that are not changed by the user.

But if your partition stays untouched during device operation, it's reasonable to include it to update.zip by adding its name to OTA_PARTITIONS variable in BoardConfig.mk

[OTA Updates overview:](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/)

> OTA updates are designed to upgrade the underlying operating system, the read-only apps installed on the system partition, and/or time zone rules; these updates do not affect applications installed by the user from Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

no, android Updater only checks the desired link based on OS and device information to get only Full OTA packages and Incremental OTA packages to update the Operating System.

but if you can build a custom rom from AOSP or LineageOS, you can customize the Updater application you desire inside the OS, to update the custom app you developed.
after that build a new rom with your customization, in that case your new OS will support anything you want to :) including OTA updater to update your custom app.